# Customize add-on installer

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm writing an add-on with the Firefox Add-on SDK and I have to perform some operations when the add-on is installed. Is there any way to customize the add-on installer? If not, I could perform these operations the first time that the add-on is loaded. How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the installer will merely install the extension, nothing fancy. It will call the `install()` method in the `bootstrap.js` of the extension but the Add-on SDK doesn't expose that functionality to the add-ons.

So if you need to initialize something - just check whether it is already initialized. E.g. if you need to create a file on first run: check whether the file already exists when your extension starts up. If it doesn't then create it.

If you cannot easily detect whether your extension is initialized then you can [use a preference](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.9/packages/addon-kit/simple-prefs.html). Something like this:

```js
var {prefs} = require("simple-prefs");
if (!prefs.firstRunDone)
{
  prefs.firstRunDone = true;
  // Your first-run code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two functions available in main.js, `exports.main` and `exports.onUnload`, which are called before the add-on is executed and before it is unloaded, respectively. You can override them like this:

```js
exports.main = function(options, callbacks)
{
    if (options.loadReason == 'install') {
        // init stuff
    }
}

exports.onUnload = function(reason)
{
    if (reason == 'uninstall') {
        // uninit stuff
    }
}
```

There are more fields in `options` and multiple possible reasons. [The source](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/load-and-unload.html).